# How do I approach this question on finding the critical points?

Tags: calculus

My online homework question reads :

> Find the critical point and determine if the function is increasing or decreasing on the given intervals. 
>   $\space y = x^{9/2} - 8 x^2 , \space x > 0$

I am unsure of what exactly do . I'm thinking I would have to use the power rule. Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy. Just take the derivative on $x>0$, $y'=\frac92 x^{7/2}-16x$. Let $y'=0$, solve this equation when $x>0$.

Comment: Which rule or rules did you use to get the derivative? Was it only the power rule?

Comment: Also why do you have the first part raised to (7/2), why isn't it raised (8/2)?

Comment: It is just the elementray of mathematical analysis. You can get the derivatives of general power functions from any calculus textbook.